# AS3 combining strings

Tags: string, actionscript-3, concatenation

I am trying to make a program combine two strings to make a name...

My code is

```
function addStudent(evt: MouseEvent)
{
var tempFirst = newStudent.firstName.text;
var tempLast = newStudent.lastName.text;
var tempStartDate = String(newStudent.startDate.text);
var tempBirthDate = String(newStudent.birthDate.text);
numStudents++;

var tempName = newStudent.firstName.text + newStudent.lastName.text;
trace(tempName);

studentList.dataProvider.addItem({label: tempName, data: tempName});

var tempStudent:student = new student(tempFirst, tempLast, tempStartDate, tempBirthDate);

studentHolder.addChild(tempStudent);

listStudents();
}
```

what the trace returns (if I input Jack Rob) is:

```
Jack
Rob
```

instead of JackRob

newStudent.firstName.text points to a movie clip called newStudent, with an input box called firstName

I have tried:

```
var tempFirst = String(newStudent.firstName.text);
var tempLast = String(newStudent.lastName.text);

var tempName = newStudent.firstName.text + newStudent.lastName.text;
var tempName = (newStudent.firstName.text).concat(newStudent.lastName.text);
var tempName = String(newStudent.firstName.text) + String(newStudent.lastName.text);
```

most of those were just me grasping at straws and *hoping* maybe something would work

essentially the goal is for the user to input a first and last name, and that first and last name is inputted into the dataProvider as one single string (JackRob)

I appreciate any help anyone can give, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have an invisible carriage return at the end of your string in the TextField. Try this :

```
var tempFirst.replace(String.fromCharCode(13), "");
```

If that works, then that is indeed the case.

I believe this happens when you are using a multiline textfield. Set it to a single line TextField in the Flash  IDE on the properties panel for the TextField(s) or use this code :

```
newStudent.firstName.multiline = false;
```